# QT draw a gray image into pseudo color (PyQt)

Tags: python, image, qt, pyqt

Currently, I have a image (numpy), and I want to draw it in QLabel with color.

A similar demo can be find: https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html. The matplotlib can display the image using imshow with a colormap.

Now, I can display the gray image in QLabel, but I do not know how to display it as a pseudo color.

The code used to display the gray image is (the self.img is what I have):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()
        img = np.zeros((256,256))
        img[0:128,0:128] = 255
        self.img = img

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)

        QImg = qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage(self.img)

        pos = QPoint(0, 0)
        source = QRect(0, 0, 256,256)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(pos, QPixmap.fromImage(QImg), source)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to show a gray image in pseudo image.

Firstly, I used opencv to generate a pseudo image:

```
disImg = cv2.applyColorMap(img, cv2.COLORMAP_AUTUMN)
```

Then, convert the image to QImage:

```
QImg = QImage(disImg.data, disImg.shape[1], disImg.shape[0], disImg.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

Finally, we can display it in QLabel by drawpixmap, and the whole code should be:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()
        img = np.zeros((256,256),dtype=np.uint8)
        img[0:128,0:128] = 255
        img[128:255,128:255] = 128
        disImg = cv2.applyColorMap(img, cv2.COLORMAP_AUTUMN)
        QImg = QImage(disImg.data, disImg.shape[1], disImg.shape[0], disImg.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.qimg = QImg

        cv2.imshow('test',disImg)
        cv2.waitKey()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)

        pos = QPoint(0, 0)
        source = QRect(0, 0, 256,256)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(pos, QPixmap.fromImage(self.qimg), source)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.resize(300,300)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```